# rolling log file is not being cleared

Tags: java, logging, logback

I'm trying to set up a rolling log appender that will rollover every day, as well as rollover when the log file reaches a certain threshold size. I've got a mostly-working setup, but if I restart the application, the rollover behavior completely breaks.

My current appender config, based on http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP

```
<appender name="logFile" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${my.log.dir}/mylog.txt</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- rollover daily -->
        <fileNamePattern>${my.log.dir}/mylog-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.txt</fileNamePattern>
        <cleanHistoryOnStart>true</cleanHistoryOnStart>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <!-- or whenever the file size reaches 10KB -->
            <maxFileSize>10KB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%-5level %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

I added a "LogSpammer" script to quickly generate log data, and the first time I run the app, everything seems fine. `mylog.txt` reaches ~10KB and gets dumped to one of the date-stamped files.

[image: Log files the first time I run. Everything seems ok]

But if I restart the application, things go haywire. The main log file never gets cleared, but it does get copied over and over, with the size of the copy growing each time. Nothing gets cleared anymore.

[image: Log files the second time I run. File sizes keep growing. Not good!]

I allowed this to run until each "rollover" was over 500KB, well above my `maxFileSize` of 10KB.

Is this behavior simply a bug? If not, am I doing something wrong with the configuration? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused by failing to fully shut down the logback `LoggerContext` when the (web)application was restarted.

In my case, the webapp was being stopped and started via `container:start` and `container:stop` in sbt. This is similar to "deploying" and "undeploying" a `.war` file on Tomcat. Since the JVM was not shutting down, nor was logback explicitly being stopped, it was able to retain a lock on the main log file. Calling `container:start` after that leads to the weirdness described in the question.

Fully shutting down the JVM and *then* running `container:start` allowed the logger/rollover to function normally.

Calling the `LoggerContext`'s `stop` method during the webapp's "unload" hook solves the problem:

```
// I happened to be using slf4j's, so I use its LoggerFactory
// class to get the LoggerContext instance
LoggerContext lc = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
lc.stop();
```